# PDO Setting PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` attribute to true in PDO, but I cannot seem to set it. I am using PHP 5.4.16 and MySQL 5.5.`PDO` and `pdo_mysql` both appear in my `phpinfo()`.

Here is how I try to set it to true.

```
public function __construct () {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8';
    $this->_db = new PDO($dsn,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

    // The following setAttribute() returns FALSE.
    $this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS, TRUE); 
}
```

I tried to look for every possible settings I can think of. What am I still missing?

Comment: How do you know you cannot set it?

Comment: If I update a row in a table with the same value, [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) usually returns 0, but if MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS is on, rowCount() returns the number of found rows, not the number of changed rows. When I test my rowCount(), it always returns 0. Also, `setAttribute()` returns TRUE if it succeeded to set an attribute, but in my case, it returns FALSE.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[It seems](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c#L613) that `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` is a **mysql connection** option. Thus, it works only as  PDO connection option as well. So, set it up this way

```
$opt  = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS   => TRUE,
    // you may wish to set other options as well
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
);
$this->_db = new PDO($dsn,DB_USER,DB_PASS,$opt);
```